# MySQL Alias and Field have same name - Which is evaluated in Having clause?

Tags: mysql, case, alias, having

I have a mysql query that is joining phone numbers from multiple tables that I can not edit and I need to create an output with the same field name as one of the tables.  I'm using a CASE statement to do this.  Here is a simple version of my query:

```
SELECT t1.`id` as id,
CASE 
    WHEN t1.`has_company_phone` = 1  THEN t1.`company_phone`
    ELSE t2.`phone`
END AS `phone`
FROM `input_table1` t1, 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `input_table2` t2
    ON (t2.`id` = t1.`matched_company_id`)
HAVING phone IS NOT NULL;
```

EDIT:
In this query, in the HAVING clause is t2.phone being evaluated, the alias phone, or both?  My goal is to have the alias evaluated in this having clause.

EG: t1.company_phone exists, but t2.phone IS NULL.  I want to include this record using the t1.company_phone and have the alias name be `phone`.  If I change the HAVING to a WHERE clause, this record will not show up.

Comment: The query works? if both tables have phone field it should throw an error

Comment: Although it is an interesting question, it is relatively easy to find it out: test it. Pls note, that you can configure mysql not to allow the use of field aliases in having clause.

Comment: @sagi - The query will work if I use an alias that is the same as a field name in one of the two tables.

Comment: @Shadow I will rephrase my question to "Is it possible to require that the alias is evaluated as that is the real goal I have.  I need to use the alias or change my field names post export and would like to make sure that when t1 has a phone number and t2 does not, that the record is still selected.

Comment: @sagi - If I change this to a where clause, the query only evaluates the phone from t2 and will not include phones when the phone exists in t1, but not in t2.

Comment: why do not use a union of the two tables as one table and then filter it? it is gonna be more clear and easy to handle by aliases.

Comment: Again: test it. If mysql evaluates the alias, it is all fine. If it does not, you have to look for alternative solutions.

Comment: @Shadow - Good call.  It took me like a min to create dummy db and test.

Comment: @Shadow, mysql only evaluates the aliases in the order by clause.

Comment: @Boody you are wrong, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html "Another MySQL extension to standard SQL permits references in the HAVING clause to aliased expressions in the select list."

Comment: @Shadow you are right, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, HAVING clause will always search the needed item from the select list.

Once found in the select list, the found item will be used.

If Not found, error is thrown.

## Update:

Actually, in ur SQL, you should replace HAVING with WHERE, since it is the same as WHERE.
Using WHERE, the confusion will be gone. WHERE clause will always use real table column, not the alias.

Answer (score 1):

replace you having by the following one:

```
group by t1.`has_company_phone`, t2.`phone`
HAVING CASE 
    WHEN t1.`has_company_phone` = 1  THEN t1.`company_phone`
    ELSE t2.`phone`
END is not null
```

and be careful to not miss the group by.

or, you can use the condition in the where without group by.

```
where CASE 
    WHEN t1.`has_company_phone` = 1  THEN t1.`company_phone`
    ELSE t2.`phone`
END is not null
```

Comment: Interesting.  So, in the GROUP BY clause, is that required for me to have access to the fields from t1 and t2 in the HAVING clause?  Does this order matter or does the CASE logic in my SELECT statement supersede any GROUP BY logic?  FYI - I had to add t1.`company_phone` as a third clause in the GROUP BY logic in order to make this work.

Comment: by the way, you can use the same condition in the where without using the group by.
i just wanted to show you that having clause always requires group by clause, i will edit my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I took Shadow's advice and constructed a test to see what would happen.  I filled t2 with a NULL phone and put a phone in t1.

The alias is evaluated because the record from t1 was included in my results.

I then reversed the values so t1.company_phone was NULL and t2.phone had a value, and reran query.  The t2.phone field name was not evaluated as no results showed up after reversing the data.

Boody's advice is probably a more explicit way of getting the functionality desired, but in my case I have about 20fields that will be merged over multiple cases and 4 tables, so the query would get really messy being that explicit.

Comment: Then wonder to use a union select. it will be the best option in your case.

Comment: @Boody - I haven't been able to find a good resource for using unions when tables are related.  My understanding of unions is that they are good when the data from the tables is not necessarily related.  Any links to using unions for related DB Tables is welcome.

Comment: you will simply do the folowing:

Answer (score 0):

with union, you will simply do the following:

```
select distinct id,  case when phone1 = '' then phone2 else phone1 end as phone from
(select matched_company_id as id, company_phone as phone1, '' as phone2 from `input_table1`
union 
select id as id, '' as phone1, phone as phone2 from `input_table2`) as t
where phone <> ''
```

then you can add any other table or field similarly.

Comment: I tried following your advice and learned that UNIONs require each table to have the same number of SELECTed columns.  The data that I need to pull together is much better suited for a join because there is unique data in each table and phone is one of the only elements that exists in multiple tables.